Remove ansi escape output from log file using cat / ansifilter or any other tools
I have this output from kubernetes conformance tests.
\u001b[90mtest/e2e/common/network/framework.go:23\u001b[0m
  Granular Checks: Pods
  \u001b[90mtest/e2e/common/network/networking.go:32\u001b[0m
    should function for intra-pod communication: udp [NodeConformance] [Conformance]
    \u001b[90mtest/e2e/framework/framework.go:652\u001b[0m
\u001b[90m------------------------------\u001b[0m

I want to read the output, removing all the escape sequences. I don't have control over the code, so I am felt with cat, less -r, ansifilter etc; even sed.
But none of these are helping me to remove the escape sequences. How can I remove those?

sed 's/\x1B\[[0-9;]\{1,\}[A-Za-z]//g' can "uncolor" its input

I have tried this, but didn't help me on mac.

So, your input literally starts with a backslash, a u, a zero etc., not the unicode escape character \u001b?

please update the question with some of your coding attempts, the (wrong) results generated by said code, and the (correct) expected result; also, please expand on your reply to pmf's comment - didn't help me - error? wrong answer? no answer? something else?

consider piping the output to xxd and then update the question with the results; we can then use xxd -r to recreate the exact output in your system


CSI (Control Sequence Introducer) sequences

For Control Sequence Introducer (CSI) commands, the ESC [ (written as \e[ or \033[ in several programming languages) is followed by any number (including none) of "parameter bytes" in the range 0x30–0x3F (ASCII 0–9:;<=>?), then by any number of "intermediate bytes" in the range 0x20–0x2F (ASCII space and !"#$%&'()*+,-./), then finally by a single "final byte" in the range 0x40–0x7E (ASCII @A–Z[\]^_`a–z{|}~).

So a POSIX solution for removing the CSIs could be:
LANG=C awk '{ gsub(/\033\[[0-?]*[ -\/]*[@-~]/, ""); print }'


edit
As the ESC characters of your CSIs seem to be JSON-escaped then you may use:
LANG=C awk '{ gsub(/\\u001[bB]\[[0-?]*[ -\/]*[@-~]/, ""); print }'


The only solution that worked for me was this snippet.
import re
import sys

output_file = sys.argv[1]
print(output_file)

def remove_escapes(text):
    # First, replace Unicode escape sequences
    text = text.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('unicode_escape')

    # Then, remove ANSI escape sequences
    ansi_escape = re.compile(r'\x1B(?:[@-Z\\-_]|\[[0-?]*[ -/]*[@-~])')
    return ansi_escape.sub('', text)


for line in open(output_file):
    try:

        parsed_line = remove_escapes(line)
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        print("UnicodeDecodeError: " + line)
        continue
    print(parsed_line, end='')

